# Inverting donut polygon in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation, donut-polygons

[image: Study Area polygon]

I extracted the study area polygon using raster to polygon tool in ArcGIS from a binary raster mask. However, I can only extract a polygon with fills outside of my study area. I tried using editor tool to draw along the needed area, but fail to plot precisely as extracted.

Is there any way to invert the polygon values so that it could be used as a mask for the central area?

Comment: It seems Singapore :)

Comment: @Shiko This is actually Northern Ontario, Canada :)

Comment: Use it to Erase a rectangle with the same extent. Or Union and select out the -1 polygon.

Comment: Interesting, Shape is very similar to Singapore :)

Comment: Use auto complete polygon in editor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this.

### **Method 1**

Like @Vince suggested, you could draw a rectangle and use the [**Erase**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) tool if your license level allows it.

### **Method 2**

Or, draw a rectangle of the same extent and perform a [**Union**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) analysis and select the polygon in the middle (including the little islands).

### **Method 3**

Or, you could draw a rectangle of the same extent, then select your complex polygon.  With your original polygon selected, select the Clip tool in the Editor toolbar:

[image]
[image]

Choose "Discard the area that intersects."
[image]

Then select the original polygon and delete it:

[image]

### **Method 4**

Another way you could do it would be to edit the vertices of your polygon and delete the four outer corners.  This will give you the inverse polygon.  Note, this might not always work, but it worked for this example.

[image]

Edit the vertices and select the four corners:
[image]

Delete the four vertices by right clicking on one of the selected ones:
[image]

Note, the result is a multipart polygon:
[image]

Comment: method 5: Start editing and there is a method "trace" just start the first point and click "Trace" than just move the mouse on one side it will trace the edge automatically.

Comment: @Florjan, good point.  Just be aware, that it may be difficult to pick up the smaller "islands" that appear to be in the original screenshot.

Comment: you are right but as soon as he want to extract the border of a country, city or area of interest there should not be small polygon inside or outside :)... whatever my comment was excessive with all these method that you have listed